# Oracle OleDB and LONG Datatype

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oledb

we do have a very aging .NET application that needs to retrieve data from a LONG datatype field in Oracle. I've been researching quite extensively and I know that datatype is deprecated but we're not in a position to do so right now.

Problem OleDb retrieves only 100 bytes from the field, it can be extended to 65535 bytes if you append Chunksize=65535 to the connection string. We do need more.

To make a long story short I tested on an 11g Oracle some queries and it seems that if you select the single field (or even the whole table) the whole field is returned, if you join tables then the field is truncated.

SELECT FIELD FROM TABLE => whole field returned
SELECT * FROM TABLE => whole field returned
SELECT * FROM TABLE T 
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2
... => truncated

I know SELECT * is bad (I didn't write that query), I obviously can use the first query and I probably will.

What I was asking for is a link to doc articles explaining how this optimization works, if any exist. It would make sense to me if it returns the whole field ONLY if you select just that field (this looks like an optimization to fight lazy developers...).

Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I can tell this is specific to OleDB. You can try to convert the values to lobs with to_lob or perhaps you can do the join first to get primary keys and then do another select specifically for the long values.

Comment: Thanks for answering ewramner. I did test with ODP.NET which gives much more control on how data is fetched (has a property on the OracleCommand object to specify how many bytes to retrieve from long fields). It really seems an OleDB "issue". Glad to learn more if someone knows. TIA